# Event Driven programming - non linear code

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have the following code (logic) in PHP:

```
$fp = fopen('fp.txt', 'w');
    if ($msg == 'say') {
        fwrite($fp, 'Hello world!');
    }
$msg = 'done';
```

To convert this into asynchronous event driven code, the author of node for PHP developers suggests I refactor it like this.

```
$fp = fopen('fp.txt', 'w');
if ($msg == 'say') {
    fwrite($fp, 'Hello world!');
    $msg = 'done';
} else {
    $msg = 'done';
}
```

And then,

```
fs.open('fp.txt', 'w', 0666, function(error, fp) {
    if (msg == 'say') {
        fs.write(fp, 'Hello world!', null, 'utf-8', function() {
        msg = 'done';
    });
    } else {
        msg = 'done';
    }
});
```

You'd clearly see, there is code duplication. 'msg = "done"' is repeated. Can this be avoided? Code duplication is bad practice right?

Is event driven programming always like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var done = function() {
    msg = 'done';
};

fs.open('fp.txt', 'w', 0666, function(error, fp) {
    if (msg == 'say') {
        fs.write(fp, 'Hello world!', null, 'utf-8', done);
    } else {
        done();
    }
});
```